# Can my Motherboard handle this Graphics card?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, computer-building

I found this mother board online (Gigabyte GA-Z87X-SLI) and this graphics card (Gigabyte GeForce GTX 770 4GB PhysX CUDA).

The graphics card has 4GB GDDR5 SDRAM.

So this is the actual problem: The motherboard supports only 1GB of allocated ram on graphics. Does this mean that the graphic card is 3GB too big or does it mean something else??

In the case that the motherboard dosn't support the graphics card: Can you recomment another SLI motherbard with at least same specs or better? (MUST be gigabyte motherboard)

Comment: The only thing you have to worry about is if your PSU is good enough to power this card.

Comment: My psy is the Corsair CX 750W. This the work fine width the graphics card right?

Comment: You tell me.  The power requirements are listed on the graphic cards specification page.

Answer (score 6):

Your card will work fine.  The amount of allocated RAM is how much on-motherboard RAM you can "shift" to use by the Onboard Graphics processor.  The onboard graphics does not have its own RAM, and must use the RAM inserted in the motherboard.

Since you will be using a dedicated graphics card, with its own RAM, this allocation of RAM does not apply to you.

Note:  I am only addressing your question regarding memory allocation limitation.  Other compatibility/stability/driver issues are a risk with any DIY video card installation

Comment: So this will not affect me in any way?

Comment: The graphics allocation will not affect you, assuming you actually install the card, install drivers, and plug the monitor into it (as opposed to the onboard video port.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that spec relates to the amount of memory that can be allocated for [Intel HD Graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HD_Graphics).

Comment: So this will affect my processor or..? (i will be using Intel core i7 4770K)

Comment: @user2372837 What do you mean by "this"? If you're planning to use a discrete graphics card and not use the HD Graphics, then, no, this will have no effect on either your CPU *or* system memory. If you can and plan to use both the HD Graphics *and* the discrete graphics card, then, yes, this affect both your CPU *and* your system memory.

Comment: So if i am just using the Gigabyte GTX 770 i will be fine? :)

Comment: @user2372837 Yes. If you want to be extra super-sure though, you could send Gigabyte an email.